# torch.nn.fucntional.interpolate(): Parameters Settings

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, interpolation

I'm using `torch.nn.functional.interpolate()` to resize an image.

Firstly I use `transforms.ToTensor()` to transform an image into a tensor, which have size of (3, 252, 252), (252, 252) is the size of the imported image. What I want to do is to create a tensor with size (3, 504, 504) with `interpolate()` function.

I set the para `scale_factor=2`, but it returned a (3, 252, 504) tensor. Then I set it like `scale_factor=(1,2,2)` and received an error of dimensional conflict like this:

`size shape must match input shape. Input is 1D, size is 3`

So what way should I do to set the parameters in order to receive (3, 504, 504) tensor?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `scale_factor` you need to give batch of images not single image. So you need to add one batch by using `unsqueeze(0)` then give it to `interpolate` function as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

img = torch.randn(3, 252, 252)  # torch.Size([3, 252, 252])
img = img.unsqueeze(0)  # torch.Size([1, 3, 252, 252])

out = F.interpolate(img, scale_factor=(2, 2), mode='nearest')
print(out.size()) # torch.Size([1, 3, 504, 504])
```

Comment: thanks so much for helping me out, I have fixed it!